# send output to pdf php

Tags: php, pdf-generation

how can i send an output on the screen to a pdf? i am generating this report, which outputs html on the screen. i want the user to click a button, and save whats on the screen as a pdf file. i am running php 5.2 and i will like to know what kind of applications/software do i need to install to be able to use php pdf library?

many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use a library. Note that it is not as simple as "send output on screen to pdf". You will need to familiarize yourself with the structure of PDFs, and learn to use the library you choose.

Libraries include:

- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
- [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html)

Comment: thanks, I just installed FPDF and tried out few examples. my question is, how can i send my html output to the pdf?

Comment: Please respect me and the rest of the community by asking a new question. Comments are not appropriate for this. Note that I said it's _not that simple_. You'll need to write your own, or find one that isn't in a state of total disrepair.

Comment: Zend_pdf has moved to here: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.pdf.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [wkhtml2pdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), it worked for me and it generates pdf pretty fast

Comment: I quite like this one. Note that the new home for this project is here: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @hobodave here. Both PDF libraries are great, but it isn't easy to just convert HTML to a pdf file. I write custom reports for my company all the time and have a preview in HTML first and then just create the PDF from scratch after the preview is accepted.

The reason for this is that it's easier to just write out the PDF WITHOUT using any HTML input than it is to try and get it working WITH the HTML.

I in any case, I recommend [FPDF](http://fpdf.org) to generate PDF files because it's fairly simple and super easy to extend. There are even ad-on's for doing HTML (although they suck).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [List of HTML to PDF converters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3178448/264628).

There are a number of libraries that will take HTML content and convert it to PDF. The best option for you really depends on your level of control of the server. Some are pure PHP classes, others require some form of binary installation.